# How can I remove elementary os totally and install ubuntu?

Tags: release-juno

I removed Windows 10 totally from pc and installed elementary juno os with full hard disk encryption. Now I want to remove elementary os entirely and install ubuntu but am having difficulties with that. I have also tried to boot ubuntu from a USB drive, but all to no success.

I'm almost a total noob, someone please help me.

Comment: Can you please explain what is happening, you said you can't boot into ubuntu, what is coming up on your screen?

Comment: Also try this Go to Boot Manager and disable the option Secure Boot.

    Change the UEFI boot order according to the medium you want to boot the computer.

Comment: It happened that the problem was with the copy of Ubuntu I was trying to install. Everything worked out after I changed it. 

Thank you for reaching out.